# How to get the reference element of a div in react?

Tags: reactjs

If I have a component, like

```
function Foo(){
    return <h1>Hey</h1>
}
```

What I can do is something like

```
const MyElement = Foo
return (<MyElement />)
```

But How can I get this reference of a `div` element?

I want to do something like

```
const WrapComponent = foo ? MyComponent : div
...
<WrapComponent>
    {/*anything*/}
</WrapComponent>
```

I just don't know how do that with a `div` element.

Comment: you wanna get reference of `div` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM elements like that are written as strings.

```
const WrapComponent = foo ? MyComponent : "div";

...
<WrapComponent>
  ...
</WrapComponent>
```

Comment: This looks crazy but I like it

Comment: it's how it works :) Try writing `React.createElement(foo ? MyComponent : "div", {}, [...])`! That's what this code would desugar to.